# api.ai intergrating webhook with nodejs for facebook messenger bots

Tags: node.js, facebook, webhooks, facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es

I am integrating facebook messenger bots through api.ai-webhook in nodejs and I'm new to node

[image: this is error image]

[github code](https://github.com/mitukulavenkatesh/messenger-bot-nodejs-fb-apiai)

In my Facebook messenger bots are working well, facing in implementing in getting the JSON data from webhook.

I have tried a lot, please help out.

Comment: this is where i feel im alone in this earth

Comment: You said you've tried a lot, yet you did not share any code to prove this. Share some code with exact problems that you faced and I'm sure somebody will be able to help.

Comment: Can you check your clientAccessToken? are you getting it properly from `env`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that everything fine except than your `authentication issue`, you have not given your `ClientAccessToken`.

You can get your secure credentials on your `agent` page

try this `URL`

https://console.api.ai/api-client/#/editAgent/xxxxxxxxxxyagent_idxxxx/

Comment: thank you for reply@abdulbarik. my doubt is where iam missing the ClientAccessToken in code. i have given all credentials

Comment: When you are calling `api` method. Are you getting proper values from `process.env`? and that token is same as accesstoken?

Comment: How have you set your Client Acces Token?

Comment: make sure to put valid clientAccessToken here `this.apiAiService = apiai(APIAI_ACCESS_TOKEN, {language: APIAI_LANG, requestSource: "fb"});`   https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/facebook/src/app.js